# Select previous data entry by datetime

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with a table with performance data. Each data table entry is for a specific counter.

```
DATA
----
dat_date     BIGINT
value     BIGINT
dat_date  DATETIME(3)
FK_dt_id  BIGINT
```

For each entries I need to compute the speed and acceleration. So I want to create a SELECT that will select a row with it PREVIOUS row.
FK_dt_id is a foreigh key on a counter type

I've try this :

```
SELECT          d1.dat_date,
            d1.value v1,
            d1.PK_dat_id
    FROM data d1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM data d2 ORDER BY d2.dat_date) d2
    ON (d2.dat_date < d1.dat_date
            AND d2.FK_dt_id = d1.FK_dt_id)
```

It works but I can't get the previous primary key, only it's value.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any of the fields in your query in your data schema.  Can you update your post either with a corrected schema or query?

Comment: This kind of requirement is very difficult to solve in "straight SQL" or even with "stored procedures," yet it is trivially easy to do if you have *any* sort of scripting engine ... in the reporting system, or in a command-line, or within your program.  You simply `order by` whatever field uniquely identifies the measure *(so as to group all occurrences of the same measure together),* then `order by` measurement-time.  As you loop, stash the (one) preceding-record, so you're "peeking one-record back." When the ID-field changes, it's the start of a new group and there is no "preceding record."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest (not necesarily the easiest) way to do things like this (with "pure" MySQL syntax) is with a little trick using user variables:

```
select @pk_data_id as prev_pk_data_id
     , @pk_data_id := (case 
           when @fk_counter_id = fk_counter_id then a.pk_data_id 
           else 0
       end) as pk_data_id
     , @fk_counter_id := a.fk_counter_id as fk_counter_id
from
    (select @pk_data_id := 0, @fk_counter_id := 0) as init
    , data as a
order by a.fk_counter_id, a.pk_data_id
```

Once you have this rowset, you can join it with your `data` table.

I'd put this result in a temporary table and use it later; something like this:

```
drop table if exists temp_tbl;
create temporary table temp_tbl
    select @pk_data_id as prev_pk_data_id
         , @pk_data_id := (case 
               when @fk_counter_id = fk_counter_id then a.pk_data_id 
               else 0
           end) as pk_data_id
         , @fk_counter_id := a.fk_counter_id as fk_counter_id
    from
        (select @pk_data_id := 0, @fk_counter_id := 0) as init
        , data as a
    order by a.fk_counter_id, a.pk_data_id;
alter table temp_tbl
    add index dId (pk_data_id),
    add index pdId (prev_pk_data_id),
    add index cId (fk_counter_id);
-- Now use the temp table to get what you need
select d1.*
     , d2.pk_data_id as prev_pk_data_id
     , d2.data_value as prev_data_value
     , d2.data_datetime as prev_data_datetime
from data as d1
     -- If you don't use the temp table, substitute 'temp_tbl' with
     -- the query from above
     inner join temp_tbl as a 
         on d1.pk_data_id = a.pk_data_id 
            and d1.fk_counter_id = a.fk_counter_id
     left join data as d2
         on a.prev_pk_data_id = d2.pk_data_id
            and a.fk_counter_id = d2.fk_counter_id
```